# Sort table by date in react, function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My sort function is not working and I think I might need to do something with state? I am not 100% sure why it isn't working. The click is fine, but the data array appears to be empty when I console.log() it. It console.logs() fine in the render method.

Here's my class:

```js
    class Orders extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            ordersObject: {}, 
            sortingOrder: 'ASC',
          };

          this.sortBy.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          this.sortBy('delivery_date', 'DESC');
        }

        renderTableData(list) {
          return (
              <tbody>
                {list && list.map(item =>
                        <tr key={item.id}>
                          <td>{(new Date(item.delivery_date)).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
                          {/* <td>{item.cupcakes}</td> */}
                        </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>
          );
        }

        //getData function removed - getsData from API 

        //sort by DESC/ASC
        sortBy(sortedKey, sortedAs) {
            const data = this.state.orders;
            let sortingOrder = this.state.sortingOrder; 
            if(sortingOrder === sortedAs) {
                sortingOrder = 'DESC'; 
                data.sort((a,b) => b[sortedKey].localeCompare(a[sortedKey]))
            }
            else {
                sortingOrder = 'ASC'; 
                data.sort((a,b) => a[sortedKey].localeCompare(b[sortedKey]))
            }
            this.setState({data, sortingOrder })
        }

        render() { 

          let {ordersObject} = this.state;
          let {orders} = ordersObject;

          return ( 
            <table id="orders"> 
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('delivery_date', 'ASC')}>Date</th>
                <th>Description <input type="text"/></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>  
                {this.renderTableData(orders)}
            </table>
          );

        }
      }
```

After destructuring, this is what the data looks like:

```js
    orders: [ 
      {id: '000', 
      delivery_date: '2018-09-15T21:25:43.000Z', 
      cupcakes: ['peanutButterBase', 'vanillaFrosting', ['sprinkles', 'coconutFlakes']]},
      {id: '001', 
      delivery_date: '2019-09-15T21:25:43.000Z', 
      cupcakes: ['peanutButterBase', 'vanillaFrosting', ['sprinkles', 'coconutFlakes']]}
    ]
```

Comment: did you tried converting date string into Date Object and sort?

Comment: I dont think that is the issue. The data variable returns an empty array.

Comment: You have too much logic here for us to read. Can you ensure which function potentially has problems? Do you think the problem is in `sortBy` function?

Comment: I think the problem is in the render method with my orders array. The data variable is returning an empty array which indicates to me I have an issue with state. I will cut it down.

Comment: @CoryAllen, it seems you never assigned a value to `this.state.orders` but you used it in `sortBy` like `const data = this.state.orders`. I think this is the reason.

Comment: I see whats wrong now...I am destructuring the orders array from the returned object. The api call returns an object NOT an array. I have to destructure to pull out the array, but this.state.orders refers to an empty array because I declared it in the state as such. I fixed that. Can I do map on ordersObject.orders instead?

Comment: I have no idea about your data structure of `this.state.ordersObject` which is set by `getData`. If there is an array `orders` in it and it is a valid array, you definitely can do `this.state.ordersObject.orders.map` and `this.state.ordersObject.orders.sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>       this.state = {
>         orders: [],
>         ordersObject: {}, 
>         sortingOrder: 'ASC',
>       };
> ```

`this.state.orders` empty

> ```
>     componentDidMount() {
>       this.getOrders(); 
>       this.sortBy('delivery_date', 'DESC');
>     }
> ```

after `getOrders()` `this.state.orders` still empty, because fetched data ...

> this.setState({'ordersObject': results})

- ... is assigned only to `ordersObject`, not `orders`
- `this.sortBy` in `componentDidMount` can't access newly loaded data

  - because it expects `this.state.orders` - should get data from `ordersObject` and save sorted to `orders` (not `data`) ? `this.setState({orders: sortedData,...`
  - you shoud use a new object returned from `sort` - states are by default compared shallowly by reference, it should be sth like `let sortedData = [...data].sort(..` because `data.sort(...` returns the same object (sorted in place);
  - you can't use data from state just after `setState` call - it's async - use callback or functions in `setState` - see docs

`render` shows 'correct' data because

> ```
> let {ordersObject} = this.state;
> let {orders} = ordersObject;
> ```

- `orders` taken from `ordersObject` (after state update) not from `this.state`

Comment: This makes sense now. Is there a way to fetch the array from the object when I make the API call?

Comment: fetch result is an object but probably contains your array ... just get it by name ... try `console.log(result)` before `setState`

Comment: you probably need sth like `this.setState({'orders': results.orders}`

Answer (score 1):

I think the code need a couple fixes:

1. `this.state.orders` is not correct as you're using this structure:

```
state: {
   ordersObject: {
      orders: [...] // from your API
   },
   sortingOrder: 'ASC'
}
```

2. When you order things, you're doing `this.setState({data, sortingOrder })`. But you're not using `this.state.data`, are you?

---

**Suggestions:**

1. just use `orders` in the state.

```
state = {
   orders: [...], //coming from the API
   sortingOrder: 'ASC'
}
```

2. so that in your sorting function, you could do `this.setState({orders:data, sortingOrder})`

Comment: Can I ask what you're doing with the three dots? ... I know thats the spread operator but what is the use case here?

Comment: @CoryAllen sorry, I wasn't clear. `orders` is just the array from your API. the tree dots means **any objects coming from the API**. It's not supposed to be in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Sample improved code. you can change as per your requirement.

```
export default class Orders extends React.Component {
  state = {
    order: [
      {
        id: "000",
        delivery_date: "2018-09-15T21:25:43.000Z",
        cupcakes: [
          "peanutButterBase",
          "vanillaFrosting",
          ["sprinkles", "coconutFlakes"]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "001",
        delivery_date: "2018-09-15T21:25:43.000Z",
        cupcakes: [
          "peanutButterBase",
          "vanillaFrosting",
          ["sprinkles", "coconutFlakes"]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "002",
        delivery_date: "2019-08-15T21:25:43.000Z",
        cupcakes: [
          "peanutButterBase2",
          "vanillaFrosting2",
          ["sprinkles2", "coconutFlakes2"]
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  renderTableData() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.state.order &&
          this.state.order.map(item => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{new Date(item.delivery_date).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
  sortBy = () => {
    let sorted = this.state.order.sort((a,b)=>{
      let date1 = new Date(a.delivery_date).toLocaleDateString();
      let date2 = new Date(b.delivery_date).toLocaleDateString();
      if (date1<date2)    return -1;
      else if(date1>date2) return  1;
      else   return  0;
    })
   this.setState({order:sorted})

  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.order)
    return (
      <table id="orders">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={this.sortBy}>Date</th>
            <th>
              Description <input type="text" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {this.renderTableData()}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-shirley-640w7)

Comment: This is nice, but it doesnt solve the issue. It's just an alternative way of doing it.